# Mantenimiento planeado para el sábado 17 de marzo a las 13 h UTC

Tags: discusión

Como indica [esta publicación en Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-march-17-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern), tendremos un evento de mantenimiento importante que causará que nuestro sitio quede en estado de solo lectura durante un rato el próximo sábado 17 de marzo a las 13 h UTC (14 h en España, 10 h en Argentina, 8 h en Colombia, 7 h en México). Al terminar el upgrade, regresaremos a la normalidad.

Estamos planeando que el evento suceda en una hora o menos.  Tenéis más información en la [publicación original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307744/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-march-17-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern).

Comment: No se seré capaz de sobrevivir UNA HORA sin [es.so]...hay vida fuera de aqui?

Comment: @Pikoh una vez me pasó, conocí gente increíble, incluso hasta decían que era mi familia ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Flxtr xD!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: ehhh.. copiamos los chistes en ingles??? seamos originales ;)